# CodeIgniter: Call to a member function row() on bool

Tags: php, codeigniter

Since I have upgraded from CodeIgniter 2.2.6 to 3.xx I have a issue I can't resolve.

### The model

```
function get_the_continue_id_pregunta_from_level($level_type, $level)
{
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('preguntas');
    $this->db->where($level_type, $level);
    $this->db->where('language', 2);
    $this->db->where("`id` NOT IN (SELECT `id_pregunta` FROM `user_as_preguntas` WHERE user_id =" . $this->session->userdata('id') .  "  )", NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->order_by("id", "ASC"); 
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if(!$q->num_rows > 0) {
        $q = FALSE;
    }

    return $q;  
}
```

### The controller

```
$g2 = $this->Qcm->get_the_continue_id_pregunta_from_level('level_1',$row->level_1);
$g2 = $g2->row()->id;
```

### Error

> Call to a member function row() on bool

Comment: look for codeigniter documentation and what is changed. For some reason the $g2 variable is a boolean value, probably false because the get_the_continue_id_pregunta_from_level throws an error

Comment: Error message: Message: Call to a member function row() on bool

Comment: It's because your query returns false. You cannot call ->row()->id on false. write an if clause to handle the false case. The problem is somewhere in your query, which doesn't work anymore, check if you have $query_builder = TRUE; in your database config

Answer (score 0):

It might be `subquery` issue you can try `get_compiled_select` like below

```
function get_the_continue_id_pregunta_from_level($level_type, $level)
    {

        $this->db->select('id_pregunta');
        $this->db->from('user_as_preguntas');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('id'));
        $where_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('preguntas');
        $this->db->where($level_type, $level);
        $this->db->where('language', 2);
        $this->db->where("`id` NOT IN ($where_clause)", NULL, FALSE);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "ASC"); 
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        if(!$q->num_rows > 0) {
            $q = FALSE;
        }

        return $q;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

**First**: you need to handle the case when your query doesn't give you any results: write in your controller something like:

```
$g2 = $this->Qcm->get_the_continue_id_pregunta_from_level('level_1',$row->level_1);

if($g2){
  $g2 = $g2->row()->id;
}else{
  echo 'no records found'; 
}
```

Now you don't call `->row()->id` on false anymore, there is no more error message, hence the error is handled.

**Second**: As your query worked before migration, you need to go through the documentation and follow the upgrade instruction. Most likely you missed in your database config file to change from `$active_record = TRUE;` to `$query_builder = TRUE;`

there could also be a problem with the session library, there were several issues documented in earlier 3.x version, so make sure you upgrade to the latest version: 3.1.10